# R - How do I solve 404 web scraping multiple links at once?

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I am very new to R, and I am trying to use it to pull historical soccer player data from the site fifaindex.com, along the lines of this page: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/06/could-an-independent-yorkshire-win-the-world-cup-data-scraping/

The goal is to do this for each year's data staring with 2012.

Players for a year are in a multi-page list, with links to their stats page. So the overall 2012 page is: https://www.fifaindex.com/players/fifa12_9/, and the player page for Leo Messi from that list is: https://www.fifaindex.com/player/158023/lionel-messi/fifa12/

The order that I need to do this operation in is (I think):

1. Define a list of links for the player list; this means building a list of:

- https://www.fifaindex.com/players/fifa12_9/?=page1 ... pageN

2. Pull each player's link from those pages; so from the above page, I need to pull:

- https://www.fifaindex.com/player/158023/lionel-messi/fifa12/
- https://www.fifaindex.com/player/20801/cristiano-ronaldo/fifa12/
- https://www.fifaindex.com/player/10535/xavi/fifa12/
- etc.

3. Scrape the data from each player site.
4. Build it into a frame where each player's info forms a row
5. Repeat annually for 2012-2023
6. Write each year as a .csv

Steps 5 and 6 are straightforward enough, but I've had to tinker a lot with the reference code.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

FIFA.12.page <- "https://www.fifaindex.com/players/fifa12_9/"

## Sets xpaths for player data
name.Xpath <- "//li[contains(@class, 'breadcrumb-item active')]"
club.Xpath <- ".team:nth-child(1) .link-team+ .link-team"
nation.Xpath <- ".pl-3 .align-items-center"
stats.Xpath <- "//span[contains(@class, 'float-right')]"

## get the links to each players page
FIFA.12.links <- tryCatch(unlist(lapply(paste0(FIFA.12.page, "?page=", 1:400), function(x) {
  player_link <- read_html(x) %>%
    html_nodes("td+ td .link-player") %>%
    html_attr("href")
})) %>%
  paste0("https://www.fifaindex.com/", .))

## Scrape data of each player page
get_player_data <- function(link) {
  #read the players web page
  read <- read_html(link)
  
  #basic data
  player.name <- read %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_all(name.Xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
  player.club <- read %>% 
    rvest::html_nodes(club.Xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
  player.nation <- read %>% 
    html_nodes(nation.Xpath) %>% 
    html_text()
  
  #general info on the player
  player.stats <- read %>% 
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_all(stats.Xpath) %>% 
    rvest::html_text()
  
  names(player.name) <- "NAME"
  names(player.club) <- "CLUB"
  names(player.nation) <- "NATION"
  names(player.stats) <- c("OVER", "HT", "WT", "FOOT", "DoB", "AGE", "POSN", "WORK RT", "WEAK FT", "SKILL MOVES", "VAL (EUR)", "VAL (USD)", "VAL (GBP)", "WAGE (EUR)", "WAGE (USD)", "WAGE (GBP)", "POSN (CLUB)", "NO (CLUB)", "JOINED", "FA DATE", "POSN (CTRY)", "NO (CTRY)", "BALL CTRL", "DRBL", "MARK", "SLIDE", "TACKL", "AGGR", "REACT", "ATTK POSN", "INTRCPT", "VISION", "COMPOSURE", "XING", "SHORT", "LONG", "ACCEL", "STAMINA", "STR", "BAL", "SPRINT", "AGILITY", "JUMP", "HEADING", "SHOT PWR", "FINISH", "LONG SHOT", "CURVE", "FK ACC", "PENS", "VOLLEY", "GK POSN", "GK DIVE", "GK HAND", "GK KICK", "GK RFLX")
  
  player.data <- c(player.name, player.club, player.nation, player.stats)
  
  ## Creates data frame
  player.df <- tibble(player.data) %>%
    cbind(player.data)
  player.df
}

## scrape the info on all players
FIFA.12.all.players.data <- tryCatch(rbindlist(lapply(FIFA.12.links, get_player_data)) %>%
  setDT() %>%
  #add an id column for each player
  .[, id := 1:.N])
```

This last function is where things fall apart. I'm getting:

```
16. open.connection(x, "rb")
15. open(x, "rb")
14. read_xml.connection(con, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = as_html, 
base_url = x, options = options)
13. read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options)
12. read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options)
11. withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) if (inherits(w, 
classes)) tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
10. suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
options = options))
9. read_html.default(link)
8. read_html(link)
7. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
6. lapply(FIFA.12.links, get_player_data)
5. rbindlist(lapply(FIFA.12.links, get_player_data))
4. setDT(.)
3. rbindlist(lapply(FIFA.12.links, get_player_data)) %>% setDT() %>% 
.[, `:=`(id, 1:.N)]
2. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
1. tryCatch(rbindlist(lapply(FIFA.12.links, get_player_data)) %>% 
setDT() %>% .[, `:=`(id, 1:.N)])
```

So the 404 error means it's looking for a page that doesn't exist, but I don't know enough to get around that, or to even know if the function is working overall.

If I can sort this out, I think I can get the data for the year and then try:

```
player.df <- tibble(player.data) %>%
  cbind(player.data)
player.df
```

To build the data frame for the year's data.

Again, I am a total noob, like one week in, so please explain it to me like I'm a baby. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works with a problem. The names vector of what in the question's code is

```
names(player.stats)
```

and the data read in are of different lengths, one has length 56 and the other 55. So I subset the names vecor keeping only the first 55 elements. This is probably not right and it should be checked against the data web pages.

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

## Scrape data of each player page
get_player_data <- function(link) {
  #read the players web page
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  #basic data
  player.name <- page %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_all(name.Xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
  player.club <- page %>% 
    rvest::html_nodes(club.Xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
  player.nation <- page %>% 
    html_nodes(nation.Xpath) %>% 
    html_text()
  
  #general info on the player
  player.stats <- page %>% 
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_all(stats.Xpath) %>% 
    rvest::html_text()
  
  names.player.stats <- c("OVER", "HT", "WT", "FOOT", "DoB", "AGE", 
                          "POSN", "WORK RT", "WEAK FT", "SKILL MOVES", 
                          "VAL (EUR)", "VAL (USD)", "VAL (GBP)", 
                          "WAGE (EUR)", "WAGE (USD)", "WAGE (GBP)", 
                          "POSN (CLUB)", "NO (CLUB)", "JOINED", 
                          "FA DATE", "POSN (CTRY)", "NO (CTRY)", 
                          "BALL CTRL", "DRBL", "MARK", "SLIDE", "TACKL", 
                          "AGGR", "REACT", "ATTK POSN", "INTRCPT", 
                          "VISION", "COMPOSURE", "XING", "SHORT", "LONG", 
                          "ACCEL", "STAMINA", "STR", "BAL", "SPRINT", 
                          "AGILITY", "JUMP", "HEADING", "SHOT PWR", 
                          "FINISH", "LONG SHOT", "CURVE", "FK ACC", 
                          "PENS", "VOLLEY", "GK POSN", "GK DIVE", 
                          "GK HAND", "GK KICK", "GK RFLX")[1:55]
  
  player.data <- data.frame(player.name, 
                            player.club, 
                            player.nation)

  player.data <- cbind(player.data, matrix(player.stats, nrow = 1))
  names(player.data) <- c("NAME", "CLUB", "NATION", names.player.stats)
  player.data
}

FIFA.12.page <- "https://www.fifaindex.com/players/fifa12_9/"

## Sets xpaths for player data
name.Xpath <- "//li[contains(@class, 'breadcrumb-item active')]"
club.Xpath <- ".team:nth-child(1) .link-team+ .link-team"
nation.Xpath <- ".pl-3 .align-items-center"
stats.Xpath <- "//span[contains(@class, 'float-right')]"

## get the links to each players page
FIFA.12.links <- lapply(paste0(FIFA.12.page, "?page=", 1:400), function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    player_link <- read_html(x) %>%
      html_nodes("td+ td .link-player") %>%
      html_attr("href")
  },
  error = function(e) e
  )
})

FIFA.12.links <- FIFA.12.links %>%
  unlist() %>%
  paste0("https://www.fifaindex.com", .)

## scrape the info on all players
FIFA.12.all.players.data <- lapply(FIFA.12.links, \(link) {
  tryCatch(
    get_player_data(link) %>%
      setDT() %>%
      #add an id column for each player
      .[, id := 1:.N],
    error = function(e) e
  )
})

err <- sapply(FIFA.12.all.players.data, inherits, "error")
sapply(FIFA.12.all.players.data[err], conditionMessage)
FIFA.12.all.players.err <- FIFA.12.all.players.data[err]

ok <- !err
FIFA.12.all.players.data <- rbindlist(FIFA.12.all.players.data[ok])
```